# ElasticSearch NEST API update value to null

Tags: c#, api, elasticsearch, nest

I am using NEST api and I am having trouble using `client.Update<T, K>` method to update a value to `null`

Is there any parameter or settings when calling update that will allow for `null` to be set trough nest api?

I know I can do it with sense.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? This works fine for merge updates but will ignore null value if set. Maybe there is an option for this?

Comment: It seems inserts work the same - ignoring null values.

Answer (score 7):

Rather then changing how null should be serialised for the entire request the safest and most isolated way to do this is to introduce a separate POCO for the update where the property you want to clear has the following attribute.

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
```

Example POCO:

```
// <summary>
/// This POCO models an ElasticsearchProject that allows country to serialize to null explicitly
/// So that we can use it to clear contents in the Update API
/// </summary>
public class PartialElasticsearchProjectWithNull
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Example update using that POCO:

```
var partialUpdate = new PartialElasticsearchProjectWithNull { Country = null };

this._client.Update<ElasticsearchProject, PartialElasticsearchProjectWithNull>(update => update
    .Id(3) 
    .Doc(partialUpdate)
);
```

which will generate the following JSON:

```
{
  "doc": {
    "country": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- In my case, I had a .NET `DateTime?` property, and I wanted to update an ElasticSearch `date` property to either null or empty.
- I couldn't do it with the [`Doc` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23796603/109941). It wouldn't push my null assignment to elasticsearch (probably because the elasticsearch `date` type doesn't support null).

So here's what I did:

1. I modified the `elasticsearch.yml` file to include [this setting](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/scripts-of-type-inline-operation-aggs-and-lang-groovy-are-disabled/2493/7): `script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: true`.
2. I modified my C# code to the following [to remove the property from the document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/docs-update.html):

   ```
       _elasticClient.Update<MyIndexType, object>(u => u
           .Id(myDocumentId)
           .Index(myIndexName)
           .Type(myType)
           .Script(string.Format("ctx._source.remove(\"{0}\")", myPropertyName))
           .RetryOnConflict(3));
   ```