# Set null to a document property and remove field from database when update

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have the below C# class.

```
public class ElasticSearchDocument
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I am also using templates for my documents, the one below is for the demonstrated test.

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "index_patterns": "documents-test*",
  "order": 2,
  "aliases": {
    "docs-test": {}
  },
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "description": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am setting the `Description` property to a `has value` and index it. Below an example in the database.

```
{
  "_index": "documents-test-2019-07-2-2",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "55096ff7-5072-4ded-b6a3-94b8e155c9d0",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": "55096ff7-5072-4ded-b6a3-94b8e155c9d0",
    "description": "has value"
  }
}
```

Querying the document, setting the `Description` property to `null` and using the below NEST `IElasticClient.UpdateAsync` method updating a document.

```
public async Task<Result> UpdateAsync(
 T document,
 string indexName = null,
 string typeName = null,
 Refresh ? refresh = null,
 CancellationToken cancellationToken =
 default) {

 var response = await Client.UpdateAsync<T,
  object>(
   document.Id,
   u => u.Doc(document)
   .Index(indexName ? ? DocumentMappings.IndexStrategy)
   .Type(typeName ? ? DocumentMappings.TypeName)
   .Refresh(refresh),
   cancellationToken);

 var errorMessage = response.LogResponseIfError(_logger);

 return errorMessage.IsNullOrEmpty() ? Result.Ok() : Result.Fail(errorMessage);
}
```

The problem is after the updating command the document is unchanged with the `description` field to have the value `has value`.

The most appropriate solution in my opinion would be somehow when setting the C# class `Description` property to null and updating Elastic Search the field to be removed from the document.

I have seen couple of answers but not sure what might have changed or if there is a better solution than [update_by_query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771354/122769) or overriding behavior of ignoring null with [property attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28564418/122769) (cumbersome) with just using NEST

Comment: I think using `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]` is your best bet in this case.

Comment: I don't like this option only because you can't really query null as well, the API using exists is much more appropriate so I'd like to use it. Maybe use raw client and update_by_query to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating the below methods.

```
public async Task<Result> UpdateAsync(
    T document, 
    string indexName = null, 
    string typeName = null,
    Refresh? refresh = null, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    Guard.Argument(document, nameof(document)).NotNull();

    await RemoveNullFieldsFromDocumentAsync(document, document.Id, indexName, typeName, cancellationToken);

    var response = await Client.UpdateAsync<T, object>(
        document.Id, 
        u => u.Doc(document)
            .Index(indexName ?? DocumentMappings.IndexStrategy)
            .Type(typeName ?? DocumentMappings.TypeName)
            .Refresh(refresh), 
        cancellationToken);

    var errorMessage = response.LogResponseIfError(_logger);

    return errorMessage.IsNullOrEmpty() ? Result.Ok() : Result.Fail(errorMessage);
}

public async Task<Result> UpdateAsync(
    string id, 
    object partialDocument, 
    string indexName = null, 
    string typeName = null,
    Refresh? refresh = null, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    Guard.Argument(partialDocument, nameof(partialDocument)).NotNull();
    Guard.Argument(id, nameof(id)).NotNull().NotEmpty().NotWhiteSpace();

    await RemoveNullFieldsFromDocumentAsync(partialDocument, id, indexName, typeName, cancellationToken);

    var response = await Client.UpdateAsync<T, object>(
        id, 
        u => u.Doc(partialDocument)
            .Index(indexName ?? DocumentMappings.IndexStrategy)
            .Type(typeName ?? DocumentMappings.TypeName)
            .Refresh(refresh), 
        cancellationToken);

    var errorMessage = response.LogResponseIfError(_logger);

    return errorMessage.IsNullOrEmpty() ? Result.Ok() : Result.Fail(errorMessage);
}

private async Task<Result> RemoveNullFieldsFromDocumentAsync(
    object document,
    string documentId,
    string indexName = null, 
    string typeName = null,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var result = Result.Ok();
    var allNullProperties = GetNullPropertyValueNames(document);
    if (allNullProperties.AnyAndNotNull())
    {
        var script = allNullProperties.Select(p => $"ctx._source.remove('{p}')").Aggregate((p1, p2) => $"{p1}; {p2};");
        result = await UpdateByQueryIdAsync(
                                        documentId, 
                                        script,
                                        indexName,
                                        typeName,
                                        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }

    return result;
}

private static IReadOnlyList<string> GetNullPropertyValueNames(object document)
{
    var allPublicProperties =  document.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();

    var allObjects = allPublicProperties.Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.IsClass).ToList();

    var allNames = new List<string>();

    foreach (var propertyInfo in allObjects)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            var isNullOrEmpty = ((string) propertyInfo.GetValue(document)).IsNullOrEmpty();
            if (isNullOrEmpty)
            {
                allNames.Add(propertyInfo.Name.ToCamelCase());
            }
        }
        else if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsClass)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.GetValue(document).IsNotNull())
            {
                var namesWithobjectName = GetNullPropertyValueNames(propertyInfo.GetValue(document))
                    .Select(p => $"{propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name.ToCamelCase()}.{p.ToCamelCase()}");
                allNames.AddRange(namesWithobjectName);
            }
        }
    }

    return allNames;
}

public async Task<Result> UpdateByQueryIdAsync(
    string documentId,
    string script,
    string indexName = null, 
    string typeName = null, 
    bool waitForCompletion= false,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    Guard.Argument(documentId, nameof(documentId)).NotNull().NotEmpty().NotWhiteSpace();
    Guard.Argument(script, nameof(script)).NotNull().NotEmpty().NotWhiteSpace();

    var response = await Client.UpdateByQueryAsync<T>(
        u => u.Query(q => q.Ids(i => i.Values(documentId)))
                .Conflicts(Conflicts.Proceed)
                .Script(s => s.Source(script))
                .Refresh()
                .WaitForCompletion(waitForCompletion)
                .Index(indexName ?? DocumentMappings.IndexStrategy)
                .Type(typeName ?? DocumentMappings.TypeName), 
        cancellationToken);

    var errorMessage = response.LogResponseIfError(_logger);

    return errorMessage.IsNullOrEmpty() ? Result.Ok() : Result.Fail(errorMessage);
}
```